The company I work for blocks Imgur, resulting in many Stack Exchange questions not loading if they contain images
The firm I recently started working for have an IT policy block on Imgur, which of course breaks the whole of Stack Exchange Network.
Any questions containing images simply don't load those images. If the images are important to understanding the question, then the question becomes totally useless.
I spoke with my IT department about this, because in my opinion the company policy doesn't make any sense.
I received an initial response stating that, quote

IMGUR is blocked company wide, as it hosts questionable adult content as well as relevant content. [sic] perhaps worth speaking to Stack overflow [sic] to let them know that this is a hurdle they should clear

It's not totally unreasonable. However, going by numbers alone, it would seem a bit strange for someone in an IT department of a company with about 200 employees to suggest that the Stack Exchange network (a company many times larger) migrate their image hosting from one platform to another, a task which is presumably expensive and difficult to do.
Regardless, I assumed this wasn't likely to work as a way forward, so I pressed the matter again stating that it didn't make much sense to me to break an entire website for this reason. Especially given I have never seen any "Adult content" on Stack Overflow, regardless of whether or not it is permitted on Imgur.
The response I got back just stated the company policy would not change unless Imgur bans adult content. This person then went on to say that

it would be easier to speak with Stack Overflow to move their photo repository than punch a gaping wide adult content hole which could land the company in a questionable IT auditing hole

I'm not really sure what to think. I've never worked for a company before where this has been an issue. And I've worked for quite a few companies by this point including very paranoid ones when it comes to security and IT security and these sorts of issues.
I have two questions

Has this been raised as an issue to Stack Exchange (the company) before?
Has Stack Exchange considered migrating their photo repository - or otherwise - what is Stack Exchange's response to my IT department so that I can go back to them with something?


"easier to speak with Stack Overflow to move their photo repository" -- ROFL. What planet does that person live on?

Imgur has banned NSFW content since mid 2023. See https://imgurinc.com/rules. In addition, SO is using their own imgur subdomain, I would be surprised to find a lot of unsafe images on that domain.

Other than the answer below also note that Stack Overflow uses a dedicated subdomain of imgur being i.stack.imgur.com.

"If the images are important to understanding the question, then question then becomes totally useless." hence why they should almost never be important about understanding the question. Unless it's actually about something that cannot be represented otherwise.

"It's not totally unreasonable." yes, not totally. Just mostly.

I got my security team to whitelist i.stack.imgur.com specifically, while leaving imgur.com itself and other subdomains blocked; they happily agreed to that exception as it is narrowly curtailed to just the SE domain use. That being said, Erik's answer below indicates the long-term, permanent solution suggested by your rather oblivious company spokesperson is, by happy coincidence, already being undertaken: moving images to a new domain altogether.

If they decline to do so and you feel you really need to access certain questions and their images to do your job, keep a record of the affected questions, and then when you have several, provide that list, along with your manager's backing, and say "hey IT, I need to see the images here to do my job, and my manager agrees". It's extra effective if you can say how much longer it will take you (if it's possible at all) to do your job without access to those images.

If push comes to shove, someone high up enough will have to remind your IT security team that their job is to "make sure company employees can do their job safely and securely", and that the important part of that phrase is "can do their job", not "safely and securely". Otherwise infosec professionals would just disconnect every computer from the internet.

"The firm I recently started working for have an IT policy block on imgur, which of course breaks the whole of stack exchange." - can't say that I agree there. I suffer from the same block, but it only makes certain meta posts annoying to read. Maybe the tags you frequent have a higher tendency to contain images.

@Gimby For many image processing and computer vision related questions, the attached images form an essential component of a proper MCVE. I'd imagine it would be problematic for lots of other graphics/UI related stuff too. I see OP uses TeX SO as well, which without images must be a real PITA.

When I was a younger man, our west coast office had a visit from the east coast folk from head office freaking the  out over our staff downloading gigs of absolutely positively must have been smut from Playboy. At the time Playboy did a lot of web services work, contributed to tooling, and hosted one of the fastest and most reliable mirrors of common web tools around. Well, Eclipse 5 had just come out, the Java team all updated, and the rest is comedic history. Fortunately no rappers were harmed in the ensuing battle.

Apologies it was Java 5 a few months earlier and Eclipse 3.somehting that supported all of the new stuff properly.

@DanMašek yes but that still makes saying "which of course breaks the whole of stack exchange" an unhealthy bit of projection. Not the best opener for a meta post. No most of it should operate just fine without images.

@Gimby Sure, that's hyperbole. I'm just providing a concrete counterexample to your "it only affects some meta posts".

The post that I wanted to read was broken because I could not see the blocked images

If your company has a problem with IMGUR, why doesn't your company contact IMGUR instead of StackOverflow?

Stack Overflow is actually already migrating their images from Imgur to a self-hosted image repository.
See Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice.

Thanks for this, I'll go back to them with this and suggest permitting content from the subdomain
